# Matching 2 strings chosen at random IF they don't exceed a limit of 12 characters?

Tags: java, random, character, generator, limit

I have a an array of Strings:

```
String[] possible_names = { "dog", "cat", "man", "woman", "boy", "girl", "table", "chair", "computer", "fat", "phone" };
```

I want to generate a character name by choosing 2 Strings from the array, and combining them, for example:

```
Random rn = new Random();
String first_name = possible_names[rn.nextInt(possible_names.length - 1)];
String last_name = possible_names[rn.nextInt(possible_names.length - 1)];
String full_name = first_name + last_name;
```

The problem is, I can't have it generate the full name if the full name exceeds 12 characters, or if first_name == last_name.

I know it would be easy to just check if the characters exceed 12 or first and last name are equal and return, but I want it to just.. try again I guess, if it fails.

I've figured out a way to do this, but I want it to be more efficient and not as memory consuming:

```
ArrayList<String> acceptable_last_names = new ArrayList<String>();
Random rn = new Random();
String first_name = possible_names[rn.nextInt(possible_names.length - 1)];
for (String s : possible_names) {
    if (s.length < (12 - first_name.length)) {
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(first_name)) {
            acceptable_last_names.add(s);
        }
    }
}
last_name = acceptable_last_names.get(rn.nextInt(acceptable_last_names.size());
```

I don't know if that code EXACTLY would work because I typed it here but I know I could do it similarly to that. My question is, is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: use some while loop, maybe

Comment: IMHO this is not really random in the sense that you'll get the same second name for the first one obtained randomly.

Comment: In terms of memory efficiency your solution would probably be the best. I don´t really see a way to make this much better. Of course there might be some little tricks to get improve this slightly but it most likely won´t be worth the time you will spent on that.

Comment: @RC. you'd need to build a good exit condition to avoid infinite/long loops.

Comment: You don't need to store multiple last names, pick one and discard it if it's bad. roughly `do { lastName = pickName() } while (!goodCombinationAndLength(firstName, lastName));`, or you re-pick both names in a loop until you found a matching pair.

Comment: @zapl The first approach assumes that all first names have a valid pairable second name. If you select a first name that's 10 characters, and the shortest surname is 4, you'll never terminate the loop.

Comment: @user2478398 example does not look like it, but in that case you could still pick both names in the loop, will not terminate in case there is no legal combination though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(possible_names);

String firstName = stringList.get(new Random().nextInt(stringList.size()));

Collections.shuffle(stringList);
Optional<String> first = stringList.stream().filter(s -> firstName.length() + s.length() <= 12 && !s.equals(firstName)).findFirst();

System.out.println(firstName + first.get());
```

So firstly you convert your array to a `List`. Then you pick a random element from it. After that you `shuffle` your list and iterate through the it searching for the first element that match your condition.

This method will only work if there is a solution, otherwise your program will throw an `exception` on `first.get()`, but you can handle it of course.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this way. Here's how I handled the exception:

  try {
   result = first_name + first.get();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
   result = first_name;
  }

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do would be:

1. create a dict where the key is the length and the value is an array of words with the same length
2. select a random number of the list of keys and get the value (aka the first length)
3. select a random number from the array containing the values
4. select a random number where the maximum length = 12 - first length
5. select a new word (like step 3)
6. profit

Comment: Wouldn´t that approach use more memory? When you want to use more names it´s going to more efficient of course but with a small amount of names like this? Not sure though so correct me if I´m wrong here^^

Comment: Yes. minimum addition would be dict of arrays vs a simple array. There are also temp allocations for step 2,4 at least. one could map the dict in an array ordered by word length instead and use the indices of the first word with a given length.